# How to remove contents of a div with Angular

Tags: angularjs

Is there an easy way to remove the contents of a div in Angular,

I have `<div class="row">` inside of which I have an ng-repeat that generates several widgets. Now if an action takes place from the `parent scope` I need to empty that `div` and call the function that does the `ng-repeat` again.

Comment: plnkr.co is down atm

Comment: `ng-repeat` will always re-evaluate if the object bound to it changes; are you doing something that isn't causing the data to change? and if so, why would it even make sense to re-render the data?

Comment: ah yeah, guess my problem is that I am updating data that builds that ng-repeat from the parent. I need to bind those scopes together

Comment: You can use a service or $rootScope ;)

Comment: Ugh, ok will post code soon, can't do a plunkr...

Comment: Def use a service for that not $rootScope.  Keep your $rootScope as clean as possible.

Comment: Yeah! I need a model in the parent scope... then use a service to update that model with data I fetch from the child scope...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code it's kind of hard to answer this, but if the ng-repeat is only thing in your div, if you update the array/object bound to the ng-repeat it will automatically update the contents of the div because the ng-repeat will re-evaluate.  You don't have to clear it out.  Now, if you have other content in the div, this solution won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Angular watches the variables on its own and adds / deletes / updates the ng-repeat on it's own when the array it lists gets updated.

So there is no need to delete it all first, you can just update the object / widget you'd like OR replace the contents of the array it lists with a new array.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are updating data outside of AngularJS.

You can try scope.$apply or an easier way is to wrap the function in an $timeout without delay:

```
$timeout(function(){ // Update your data });
```

Comment: I'm going to try build out a decent plunkr tomorrow to reflect this. It's rather complicated to post a question without one. Basically got a parent and child situation, a JSON array with hundreds of objects, and changing the date needs to update the model everywhere.